# How to use the noreferrer feature with window.open and get a non-null reference to the child window?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'd like to programmatically open a new window (i.e. via `window.open`) and modify the contents *without*

- making myself vulnerable to reverse tabnabbing via a non-null `window.opener` in the child window
- leaking potentially sensitive urls or query parameters via the `Referer` header

Using the `noreferrer` feature (i.e. `window.open(url, target, "noreferrer")`) seemed to be the most straightforward option but according to [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#window-open-steps) (see step 15), this will always cause the return value to be `null`.

Is there a way to open a new window without passing a `Referer` header, set `opener` to `null`, and still have a non-null reference to the opened window?

Comment: genuinely interested for 2/ if [referrer-policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy) works for `window.open` calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
var otherWindow = window.open();
otherWindow.opener = null;
otherWindow.location = targetUrl;
```

Comment: `opener` is accessible even on cross-origin windows: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#crossoriginproperties-(-o-) So you can even do `var otherWindow = window.open(targetUrl); otherWindow.opener = null;`

Comment: This doesn't really work because, as stated, I want to also avoid sending a `Referer` header. When you set the location on the window, a `Referer` header will be sent with the parent window's url.

Comment: @MichaelWu not sure if there is a solution